# Content not scaling to various screen sizes even using "em"s

Tags: html, css, scale, font-size

I'm relatively new to webpage design, but as I understand it, em is supposed to scale to any screen size. I am everything defined as em or % with the exception of a few trivial borders, and yet, when I try to look at it on different screens, none of div or their content scale.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Name</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style2.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="Center">
    <div id="home1">
        <img src="WelcomeScreen.jpg" alt="Welcome!"/> 
    </div>
</div>

<div id="Left">
    <div class="button1" id="a1">
    </div>
    <div class="button1" id="a2"></div>
    <div class="button1" id="a3"></div>
</div>

<div id="Right">
    <div class="button1" id="a4"></div>
    <div class="button1" id="a5"></div>
    <div class="button1" id="a6"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

div{
display: inline-block;
}

div img{
height: auto;
width: 100%;
border: 3px solid black;
border-radius: 2em;
}

#home1{
position: relative;
border: 1px solid black;
border-radius: 2em;
margin-top: 4em;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -25em;
width: 50em;
height: 37.5em;
box-shadow: 0em 0em 5em 2em #000000;
}

.button1{
height: 10em;
width: 15em;
border: 1px solid black;
border-radius: 1em;
}

#a1{
position: relative;
margin-top: 1em;
margin-left: 1em;
}
#a2{
position: relative;
margin-top: 6em;
margin-left: 1em;
}
#a3{
position: relative;
margin-top: 6em;
margin-left: 1em;
}

#a4{
position: relative;
margin-top: 1em;
margin-right: 2em;
}

#a5{
position: relative;
margin-top: 6em;
margin-right: 2em;
}
#a6{
position: relative;
margin-top: 6em;
margin-right: 2em;
}


#Center{
height: 50em;
width: 60em;
padding: 0.8em;
border: 1px solid black;
left: 50%;
}

#Left{
float: left;
height: 50em;
width: 16em;
padding: 1em;
border: 1px solid black;
}

#Right{
align-content: center;
float: right;
height: 50em;
width: 16em;
padding: 1em;
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: `em` is relative to the font size, not the screen size..

Answer (score 0):

Em is unit meaning "default browser's font size".

What you should do is:

1. Read about CSS media queries and responsive breakpoints
2. Use `html { font-size: X px }` respectively for each breakpoint
3. Use rems instead of ems. (Rem is "default font size for given page", and that default size you have set in step 2.)

Answer (score 0):

As Gaby mentioned in the comments, ems are simply relative to the font size, they won't scale to fit the browser width. They're still good to use for font-sizing because when users make the font size bigger on their end, the content is less likely to break, since it's not defined in pixels.

However, if you want elements to scale, you should be using percents ie `width: 50%` instead of `width: 50em`. This way, the element will always be 50% of the parent's width. *Note that you'll need to give the parent element a width in percents as well to see the scaling in action*

If you want more control of your layout at different sizes, you should look into media queries. There are lots of posts out there, but this should get you started. http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/